# Define options for type with PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is there a way to define multiple options (to serve as an internal overview / guide) when using `PropTypes`, as a companion for `defaultProps`?

I usually just add comments to serve as an overview of the possible options, but is there a better way?
E.g. when I have a button that can take different size (props) arguments such as `standard`, `large`, `subtle`, `fitToContent`, ...

*As a sidenote / side question — I want / need to learn TypeScript, is this something that can be done with TS?*

Comment: You can achieve this with TS since it's statically typed, all available props can be seen when you're using the Component, even the options of a particular prop. For example: `size: 'small' | 'large'`

Comment: Either `flowjs` or preferably `typescript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript there is something called literal types it's mean that it's will strict you to output you want like the example @konekoy show in the comment

```
size: "standard" | "large" | " subtle" | etc.
```

I recommend you start learning TypeScript it's not that hard
and another bonus with TypeScript the IDE works with it perfectly and can make much better IntelliSense.
there will be a little difference between React with js and ts but it's really minor

Comment: if you need any more help you can contact me on Discord

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciated

Comment: @ChristophBerger forgot to put the user 
TalOrlanczyk#9541